# Ansible Tower REST API: Is there any way to get the logs/output of a job?

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

I have a Ansible job started by another Process. Now I need to check the status of the current running job in Ansible Tower.

I am able to track the status whether it is **running/success/failed/canceled** with `/jobs/{id}` using [REST API](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html).

But I would also need the information of the console logs/ouputs of the task for processing as well. Is there any direct API call for the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the job log via a link similar to:

`https://tower.yourcompany.com/api/v1/jobs/12345/stdout?format=txt_download`

Your curl command would be similar to:
`curl -O -k -J -L -u ${username):${password} https://tower.company.com/api/v1/jobs/${jobnumber}/stdout?format=txt_download`

obviously replacing ${username}, ${password}, and ${jobnumber} with your own values

The curl flags used:

- -O : output the filename that is actually downloaded
- -k : insecure SSL (don't require trusted CAs)
- -J : content header for file download https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-J
- -L : follow redirects
- -u : username and password

Comment: Is there a way to get filtered output?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this via their restful call.
To get the job number use a GET against `https://yourtowerinstance/api/v2/job_templates/`
this will return your templates, and their IDs

To get the output in real time I use this powershell code

```
    $stdouturl = "https://yourtowerinstance/api/v2/jobs/$($templateResult.id)/stdout/?format=txt"

$resultstd = Invoke-Restmethod -uri $stdouturl -Method 'Get' -Headers $authHeader
while ($resultstd -notmatch 'PLAY RECAP') {
    $resultstd = Invoke-Restmethod -uri $stdouturl -Method 'Get' -Headers $authHeader
    start-sleep -s 5
}
$resultstd
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you launch a template you get the job-id in response but I don't think there is a API to get the output of the job. However from the dashboard under jobs section you can download the individual job output.