# Download Ansible Tower log output directly to a output file on managed remote server

Tags: rest, ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-tower

Could someone please help on "How to download Ansible Tower execution result to a log file on a particular remote server?".

I couldn't find much results on "How to automatically download the result of execution?".

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question similar to [Ansible Tower REST API: Is there any way to get the logs/output of a job?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49821341/6771046)

According the [Tower API Reference Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html): **Jobs**, the following call might work from or on your remote server.

```
curl --silent -u ${TOWER_USER}:${TOWER_PASSWORD} -JL https://${TOWER_URL}/api/v2/jobs/${JobID}/stdout?format=txt_download -o job_${JobID}.log
```

resulting into the output of a file called `job_${JobID}.log`.

You may transfer this in to an Ansible task, ideally by **not** using the `shell` module.

Comment: If you need more than the `stdout` alone and want the FULL output (as if you were to click on each task result and look at the JSON individually), it may also be useful to see `https://${TOWER_URL}/api/v2/jobs/${JobID}/job_events >> outfile` but note that these are paginated results so you would need to iterate through and fetch page by page (`/?page=###` -- unless there's a trick I'm missing to get it all!)